# Update stored procedure no getting column

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, complextype

I have this stored procedure:

```
SELECT     
    s.Id AS IdCategory,
    s.Description AS Category,
    COUNT(s.Description) AS TotalYEAR
INTO 
    #AuditYear
FROM    
    [dbo].[Audit] aa  (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[AuditActOrCondition] a (NOLOCK) ON aa.Id = a.IdAudit 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ActOrCondition] ac (NOLOCK) ON a.IdActCondition = ac.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACType] t (NOLOCK) ON ac.Type = t.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACSubType] s (NOLOCK) ON ac.Subtype = s.Id
WHERE 
    YEAR(aa.CreateDate) = (SELECT YEAR 
                           FROM [dbo].[KPIS] k1 (NOLOCK) 
                           WHERE k1.Id = @Id)
GROUP BY  
    s.Id, s.Description


SELECT     
    s.Id AS IdCategory,
    s.Description AS Category,
    COUNT(s.Description) AS TotalMonth 
INTO 
    #AuditMonth
FROM
    [dbo].[Audit] aa  (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN   
    [dbo].[AuditActOrCondition] a (NOLOCK) ON aa.Id = a.IdAudit 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ActOrCondition] ac (NOLOCK) ON a.IdActCondition = ac.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACType] t (NOLOCK) ON ac.Type = t.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACSubType] s (NOLOCK) ON ac.Subtype = s.Id
WHERE 
    MONTH(aa.CreateDate) = (SELECT MONTH 
                            FROM [dbo].[KPIS] k1 (NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE k1.Id = @Id)
GROUP BY  
    s.Id, s.Description

SELECT 
    y.IdCategory, y.Category,
    ISNULL(m.TotalMonth,0) AS TotalMonth,
    y.TotalYEAR
FROM 
    #AuditYear y
LEFT JOIN 
    #AuditMonth m ON y.IdCategory = m.IdCategory
```

And I want to add column called `BranchOfficeId` so I do a `INNER JOIN` like:

```
SELECT     
    s.Id AS IdCategory,
    s.Description AS Category,
    COUNT(s.Description) AS TotalYEAR,
    b.BranchOfficeId 
INTO 
    #AuditYear
FROM    
    [dbo].[Audit] aa  (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Department] AS d (NOLOCK) ON aa.IdDepartment = d.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[BranchOffice] AS b (NOLOCK) ON b.BranchOfficeId = d.BranchOfficeId
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[AuditActOrCondition] a (NOLOCK) ON aa.Id = a.IdAudit 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ActOrCondition] ac (NOLOCK) ON a.IdActCondition = ac.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACType] t (NOLOCK) ON ac.Type = t.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACSubType] s (NOLOCK) ON ac.Subtype = s.Id
WHERE 
    YEAR(aa.CreateDate) = (SELECT YEAR 
                           FROM [dbo].[KPIS] k1 (NOLOCK) 
                           WHERE k1.Id = @Id)
GROUP BY  
    s.Id, s.Description, b.BranchOfficeId


SELECT     
    s.Id AS IdCategory,
    s.Description AS Category,
    COUNT(s.Description) AS TotalMonth 
INTO 
    #AuditMonth
FROM
    [dbo].[Audit] aa  (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN   
    [dbo].[AuditActOrCondition] a (NOLOCK) ON aa.Id = a.IdAudit 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ActOrCondition] ac (NOLOCK) ON a.IdActCondition = ac.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACType] t (NOLOCK) ON ac.Type = t.Id
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ACSubType] s (NOLOCK) ON ac.Subtype = s.Id
WHERE 
    MONTH(aa.CreateDate) = (SELECT MONTH 
                            FROM [dbo].[KPIS] k1 (NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE k1.Id = @Id)
GROUP BY  
    s.Id, s.Description

SELECT 
    y.IdCategory, y.Category,
    ISNULL(m.TotalMonth,0) AS TotalMonth,
    y.TotalYEAR
FROM 
    #AuditYear y
LEFT JOIN 
    #AuditMonth m ON y.IdCategory = m.IdCategory
```

But when I update my complex type it only get columns:

```
public int IdCategory { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public int TotalMonth { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> TotalYEAR { get; set; }
```

Can anyone explain me why I can't get `BranchOfficeId` value? Regards

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT y.IdCategory
        ,y.Category
        ,ISNULL(m.TotalMonth,0) AS TotalMonth
        ,y.TotalYEAR
         FROM #AuditYear y
            LEFT JOIN #AuditMonth m
            ON y.IdCategory = m.IdCategory
```

The #AuditYear is the result from your first select, then, you only need the column BranchOfficeId in the last select:

```
SELECT y.IdCategory
        ,y.Category
        ,ISNULL(m.TotalMonth,0) AS TotalMonth
        ,y.TotalYEAR, y.BranchOfficeId
         FROM #AuditYear y
            LEFT JOIN #AuditMonth m
            ON y.IdCategory = m.IdCategory
```